# How to unset (or hide) all environment variables prior to starting pytest

Tags: environment-variables, pytest

In Jenkins, I am running my pytests inside of a Docker container that has several environment variables set.  Before running ANY tests, I would like to ensure that these environment variables are empty or not-available to the code running in the tests.

Why do this?

- I want to understand the dependencies of my source code on the environment variables.  If a chunk of code requires an environment variable be set, I would prefer to explicitly set/mock it.
- I want developers to be able to easily run the tests locally in their IDE without needing to do complex env setup.  Right now people frequently add code that depends on the environment variables which causes the tests to break when running locally.

Is there a pytest fixture that I should consider using to unset or hide all environment variables?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/319043/runing-a-command-without-inheriting-parents-environment

Comment: You can also clear `os.environ` in a custom fixture, but this will only help if the code reads env vars from it and not e.g. by parsing the `subprocess.run(["env"])` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same Problem and solved it with a mixture of `pytest` and `unittest`. As the latter is standard python, I think its a valid way to go:

```
import pytest    
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture
def mock_env(monkeypatch):
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, clear=True):
        monkeypatch.setenv(new_var, value)
        yield

def test_func(mock_env):
    # test code
```

So we just use `unittest` to clear the environment and set it with pytests `monkeypatch`. The `yield` is needed to prevent the function and the mock context from exiting.

Of course, if you just imported `unittest` its a personal choice if you still need `monkeypatch` or not.

Comment: i might be missing something here, but what is `monkeypatch` supposed to be in this case/example?

Comment: Its just pytests fixture to set environment variables: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#std-fixture-monkeypatch

Might be possible without it. But it worked and so I stopped trying ;-)